# Regex match all single underscores surrounded in one or more letters or numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find all **single underscores** that are surrounded by one more letters or numbers in a string. E.g:

```
ChIJww8705e81qjAgU_IJww8705ZZkW_e81qjAg_ChIJww8
```

*Note: the length of the string and number of underscores is unknown. The string may also contain multiple underscores together. *

I'm sure this is easy but I'm not super savvy with regex. This is what I have so far, but it's only matching the first occurrence.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+(_)+[a-zA-Z0-9]
```

The end goal is to replace the underscores with another character.

Comment: Do you have to use regex? otherwise, just do  'ChIJww8705e81qjAgU_IJww8705ZZkW_e81qjAg_ChIJww8.split("_") and the size of the resulting array will give you an answer.

Comment: Ah I should have mentioned that the strings I'm matching against could contain multiple underscores in a row. Eg: foo___bar___rad I just need the ones with a single underscore surrounded by characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9])_([a-zA-Z0-9])
```

You can use it like this for replacing it with '-'

```
str.replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9])_([a-zA-Z0-9])/g, "$1-$2")
```

you can add any other character or string in place of '-'

This regex matches (A-Z or a-z or 0-9), an underscore and (A-Z or a-z or 0-9)

**Explanation:**

`[a-zA-Z0-9]` matches small or capital alphabets and numbers.

`()`: make a group of a match, `([a-zA-Z1-9])` make a group of it to use it later in the solution.

and `_` obviously matches underscore.

`$1` and `$2` in the replacement string refers to the first and second match group in the regex.

Comment: Please explain – for future visitors, as well as the OP – what that regular expression matches.

Comment: `\w` is already a superset of `\d`, and it also includes `_`, which it probably shouldn't. It should really be be `[a-z\d]` or `[a-zA-Z\d]` instead of `[\d\w]`. For readability in the character class, many people might use `0-9` instead of `\d`, since inside a character class `\d` isn't saving much.

Comment: Updated @DavidThomas, thanks for mentioning ShadowRanger, but was already updating it after David's comment

Comment: @torazaburo nop.. for that your solution works great and well explained.. +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

In cases like `a_b_c`, to avoid `b` being consumed by the match including the first underscore (which would stop the second underscore from being matched), you can use a lookahead, which checks for a match at the current position but does not consume any input. (Even easier would be a lookahead and lookbehind, but JavaScript doesn’t support lookbehinds.)

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9]_(?=[a-zA-Z0-9])/g
```

Apart from that, the only reason you would be getting only one match was that you didn’t include the `/g` (global) flag. `/g` affects `String#match` by causing it to return all matches instead of all captures for the first match, `String#replace` by causing it to replace all instances instead of just the first one, and `RegExp#exec` by causing it to continue matching from the previous match so you can use it in a loop.

Here’s a replacement of all such underscores with a fixed string, `**`:

```
s.replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9])_(?=[a-zA-Z0-9])/g, '$1**');
```

And if you do need the full surroundings to make the replacement, you can keep the `+` quantifier in the first group and put a capturing group in the lookahead. (That still works!)

An example might make that clearer – here’s one that will add every pair of numbers in a string like `150_297_832`:

```
var s = '150_297_832';
var result = s.replace(/(\d+)_(?=(\d+))/g, function (match, left, right) {
    var sum = parseInt(left, 10) + parseInt(right, 10);
    return ' (' + sum + ') ';
});

// result = ' (447)  (1129) 832';
// 447 is 150 + 297, 1129 is 297 + 832, 832 was not replaced
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, consider your regex:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+ // a-z, A-Z and 0-9, matched one or more times (greedy) 
(_)+         // _ in capture group, matched one or more times (greedy)
[a-zA-Z0-9]  // a-z, A-Z and 0-9, matched exactly one time
```

You do not need to match multiple characters in front of the underscore, neither do you need to match multiple underscores:

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9]_[a-zA-Z0-9]/g
//                       ^ Note the global flag
```

You can also use `\w` which is equal to: `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, but note it also matches an underscore:

```
/[\w]_[\w]/g
```

To tie it all together with match group and `.replace(search, replacement)`:

```
// Replace all underscores with dashes (-)
var str = 'ChIJww8705e81qjAgU_IJww8705ZZkW_e81qjAg_ChIJww8';
str.replace(/([\w])_([\w])/g, '$1-$2');
//                             ^  ^
//                             |  Refers to second match group `([\w])`
//                             Refers to first match group `([\w])`
```

Comment: This one doesn't work if the string has multiple underscores. eg: `ChIJww8705e81qjAgU___IJww8705ZZkW_e81qjAg___ChIJww8` In that example I'd only want to capture the underscore between the *W* and *e* character.